# Plot a df with lines

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I need to plot a df where each column represents a date (and has name = 20180905) and each row represents a value (sometimes NaN), for the given date, excepting the rows from the column 'Id' which I need to exclude from the plot. I tried to plot the dates on the X axis and the values on the Y, but I couldn't succeed.

so far my df looks like
[image: screen]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/12/29ef5590ec4e73859d714c25f57f7c29-full.png))</sub>

code I tried to use
remid=rep19_norm.iloc[:, :-1] # to avoid printing 'Id' which is the last column

remid.plot()

and results are

[image: capture2]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/11/12/73e8a09f2cf37d0a787de45f8819fd40-full.png))</sub>

Comment: Can you give an example dataframe and the expected output?

Comment: df is exactly the one I published. and the expected output is a graph like this one !(https://images.app.goo.gl/T6Arsn4EgEcvZEfo8) where each line corresponds to each row of the df